# Docker multi-staged maven build split dependency resolve and compilation

Tags: java, maven, docker

I'm trying to setup a multi-staged dockerfile for my maven based java project. Here's what I'm using so far:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 as build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

# Bundle app source
COPY src src
RUN mvn package

### STAGE 2: Production Environment ###
FROM jboss/wildfly:17.0.0.Final

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/Appname.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/Appname.war

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin123 --silent
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

The question is about the `mvn` commands. I see that `mvn dependency:go-offline` downloads some dependencies, which is great. But then `mvn package` downloads some more packages. Why? How can I have two steps:

- one for resolving and downloading all dependencies
- one for compiling the source code and creating the .war file

### EDIT

using `mvn package -o`, I get the following package not being found:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project monolith: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
```

I think it's related to the build plugin in `pom.xml`. Any thoughts?

```
<build>
    <finalName>Monolith</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <!--<configuration>-->
                <!--<webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Use `mvn package -o` to be offline and post which dependency is being donwnloaded. Then show `pom.xml` so we can see where it's defined.

Comment: there you go. maybe some version mismatch in the build plugins, I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely affected by [MDEP-82 go-offline / resolve-plugins does not resolve all plugin dependencies](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82) bug which is currently unresolved.

As per [this comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82?focusedCommentId=16471815&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16471815) in the MDEP-82 issue this can potentially be fixed by specifying maven-dependency-plugin version instead of using the default one:

> then define explicitiely the maven-dependency-plugin version used for go-offline to not depend on default version defined inside Maven:
>
> `mvn -s settings.xml org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:go-offline`

Answer (score 0):

The maven dependency plugin has some limitations and so it doesn't download all the dependencies. This is mostly OK when you work locally, because a single `mvn package` command would do the trick.

But this is not well suited for maven running inside Docker container. After a lot of searching, today I stumbled upon the [go-offline-maven-plugin](https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin). I tried it with the small project I'm using to test this and it worked.

Here is how to include it in your pom.xml:

```
<!-- ... -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.qaware.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>go-offline-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <dynamicDependencies>
                    <DynamicDependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20.1</version>
                        <repositoryType>PLUGIN</repositoryType>
                    </DynamicDependency>
                </dynamicDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ... -->
    </plugins>
    <!-- ... -->
</build>
<!-- ... -->
```

The `dynamicDependencies` are dependencies, which are not really present in any `pom.xml`, but are instead hard-coded in the plugins. The most common case is the surefire plugin, which loads the needed dependency depending on your tests (e.g. JUnit4/5, TestNG, etc.).

Lastly, you need to run this plugin from your `Dockerfile`. This should work:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 as build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn -e -B de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:resolve-dependencies

# Bundle app source
COPY src src
RUN mvn -o -e -B package

### STAGE 2: Production Environment ###
FROM jboss/wildfly:17.0.0.Final

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/Appname.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/Appname.war

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin123 --silent
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```